# Amazon API Gateway and EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, lambda

I have gone through the Amazon API gateway and lamda  and its i understand the combination as lamda proving computation.

Is lamda is providing computation only or it can connect to EC2 linux instance and further to RDS?

Or Amazon API gateway direct connect to EC2 Linux instance?

I am confused?

Can any one help me on this?

Thanks

Comment: API gateway can connect to EC2 directly as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in my opinion you are looking at serverless framework which is an API gateway which is configured with stages that send requests to your lambda function.

There is no need for Ec2 instance usage. Lambda function will establish connections with your database and make calls to it. Your database setup can be either private or public.

Additionally, on top of your api gateway you can implement something like cloudfront distribution and WAF which will provide further enhancements to your setup.

Comment: Thanks , I got it. One question ? we have to write user access logic and output function in lamda than?

Comment: and if we are not going with serverless, what other option can i choose?

Comment: You can use AWS Batch where you are using docker images and that runs your tasks. You may want to opt out for running ec2 instances with load balancer on top of it. Or you might want to use something like fargate, Eks or ecs. It really depends what your vision is.